# What does urlfetch send instead of None value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urlfetch

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
def track_event(category, value=None):
  form_fields = {
    'ec': category,
    'ev': value
  }
  form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
  result = urlfetch.fetch(url='http://example.com',
      payload=form_data,
      method=urlfetch.POST)
  return result.status_code

track_event('category')
```

What is sent as `ev` value when `value` is `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using [`urllib.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) which convert `None` to a string `'None'`:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode({'ev': None})
'ev=None'
```